# Extending continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ to continuity on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}= \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, real-numbers

I am asking myself the following question:

> Assume that $(0,\infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are endowed with the euclidean metric repsectively. Let $$f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ be a decreasing continuous function. Then the limit $$f(0):= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0, x>0} f(x)$$ exists in $(-\infty,+\infty]$.
>
> Can we then define a topology, or a metric, such that $f$ is continuous as a function from $[0,\infty)$ to $(-\infty,+\infty]$ or to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Make $U\subset (-\infty,+\infty]$ open if for every $x\in U$, if $x\neq+\infty$ then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset U$, and if $+\infty\in U$ then also there is $\delta>0$ such that $(\delta,+\infty]\subset U$.

Comment: Thank you! If you write this comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: You can write it, proving that it does make the extension of $f$ continuous.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838474/328173

Comment: This raises doubt on both questions.

Comment: Denote $\hat{f}$ to be the extension of $f$ to $[0,+\infty)$. Continuity of $\hat{f}$ at every point $x\neq0$ is clear because $\hat{f}$ is equal to $f$ on a neighborhood of $x$. To prove the continuity of $\hat{f}$ at $0$, let $\epsilon>0$. If $f(0)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ is finite, then there is $\delta>0$ such that $0<x<\delta$ implies that $|\hat{f}(0)-\hat{f}(x)|=|f(0)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Therefore, $\hat{f}$ is continuous at $0$. If $f(0)=+\infty$. Then there is $\delta>0$ such that if $0<x<\delta$ then $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)>\epsilon$. Therefore, $\hat{f}$ is continuous at $0$ as again.